# How do i change react table buttons styles

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Does anyone know a way to change the styles for 'next' and 'previous' buttons underneath a react table from [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme)?

[image: Image of the buttons]

Here is the short example of the component defined:

```
    <ReactTable
      manual
      minRows={0}
      pageSize={1}
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      pages={0}
      showPagination={true}
    />
```

Here is the link to codesandbox (Sandbox for complete example): https://codesandbox.io/embed/olx7x6jkkz

Comment: put your code here

Comment: ould you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Of course that is feasible but you need to share the code of react table you tried which isn't working so that we can help you with styling the buttons

Answer (score 2):

I replaced the default pagination component with my own pagination component, based on the 'reactstrap' pagination component. Replacing the component was simple.

```
import ReactTable, { ReactTableDefaults } from 'react-table';
import Pagination from './Pagination.component';

Object.assign(ReactTableDefaults, {
  PaginationComponent: Pagination
});
```

Then the code for my pagination component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { Pagination as BSPagination, PaginationItem, PaginationLink } from 'reactstrap';

const defaultButton = ({ ...props }) => <PaginationLink {...props} />;

export default class ReactTablePagination extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.getSafePage = this.getSafePage.bind(this);
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
    this.applyPage = this.applyPage.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      page: props.page
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ page: nextProps.page });
  }

  getSafePage(page) {
    if (Number.isNaN(page)) {
      page = this.props.page;
    }
    return Math.min(Math.max(page, 0), this.props.pages - 1);
  }

  changePage(page) {
    page = this.getSafePage(page);
    this.setState({ page });
    if (this.props.page !== page) {
      this.props.onPageChange(page);
    }
  }

  applyPage(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    const page = this.state.page;
    this.changePage(page === '' ? this.props.page : page);
  }

  getFirstRecord(page, pageSize, totalSize) {
    if (!totalSize) {
      return 0;
    }
    return page * pageSize + 1;
  }

  getLastRecord(page, pageSize, totalSize, currentCount) {
    if (!totalSize) {
      return 0;
    }
    // const rec = (page + 1) * pageSize;
    return this.getFirstRecord(page, pageSize, totalSize) + currentCount - 1;
  }

  getPageElement = index => {
    const { page } = this.props;
    return (
      <PaginationItem key={index}>
        <PaginationLink
          className={classNames({ 'this-page': page === index })}
          onClick={() => this.changePage(index)}
        >
          {index + 1}
        </PaginationLink>
      </PaginationItem>
    );
  };

  pagination = () => {
    const items = [];
    const { page, pageRangeDisplayed, totalSize, pageSize, marginPagesDisplayed } = this.props;

    const BreakView = () => (
      <PaginationItem>
        <PaginationLink disabled>{'...'}</PaginationLink>
      </PaginationItem>
    );

    const pageCount = Math.ceil(totalSize / pageSize);

    if (pageCount <= pageRangeDisplayed) {
      for (let index = 0; index < pageCount; index++) {
        items.push(this.getPageElement(index));
      }
    } else {
      let leftSide = pageRangeDisplayed / 2;
      let rightSide = pageRangeDisplayed - leftSide;

      if (page > pageCount - pageRangeDisplayed / 2) {
        rightSide = pageCount - page;
        leftSide = pageRangeDisplayed - rightSide;
      } else if (page < pageRangeDisplayed / 2) {
        leftSide = page;
        rightSide = pageRangeDisplayed - leftSide;
      }

      let index;
      let currPage;
      let breakView;
      let createPageView = index => this.getPageElement(index);

      for (index = 0; index < pageCount; index++) {
        currPage = index + 1;

        if (currPage <= marginPagesDisplayed) {
          items.push(createPageView(index));
          continue;
        }

        if (currPage > pageCount - marginPagesDisplayed) {
          items.push(createPageView(index));
          continue;
        }

        if (index >= page - leftSide && index <= page + rightSide) {
          items.push(createPageView(index));
          continue;
        }

        if (items[items.length - 1] !== breakView) {
          breakView = <BreakView key={index} />;
          items.push(breakView);
        }
      }
    }

    return items;
  };

  render() {
    const {
      // Computed
      pages,
      // Props
      page,
      pageRangeDisplayed,
      marginPagesDisplayed,
      showPageSizeOptions,
      pageSizeOptions,
      pageSize,
      showPageJump,
      canPrevious,
      canNext,
      onPageSizeChange,
      className,
      totalSize,
      currentCount,
      PreviousComponent = defaultButton,
      NextComponent = defaultButton
    } = this.props;

    const PageItem = defaultButton;

    return (
      <div
        className={classNames({
          'ke-pagination-container': true,
          'd-flex': true,
          'flex-row': true,
          'p-2': true,
          'justify-content-between': true
        })}
      >
        <div className={classNames({ 'paging-buttons': true, 'flex-fill': true })}>
          <BSPagination size="sm">
            <PaginationItem>
              <PageItem
                previous
                onClick={() => {
                  if (!canPrevious) return;
                  this.changePage(page - 1);
                }}
                disabled={!canPrevious}
              >
                {'<'}
              </PageItem>
            </PaginationItem>

            {this.pagination()}

            <PaginationItem>
              <PageItem
                next
                onClick={() => {
                  if (!canNext) return;
                  this.changePage(page + 1);
                }}
                disabled={!canNext}
              >
                {'>'}
              </PageItem>
            </PaginationItem>
          </BSPagination>
        </div>
        {showPageSizeOptions && (
          <span
            className={classNames({
              'flex-fill': true,
              'select-wrap': true,
              '-pageSizeOptions': true,
              'text-center': true
            })}
          >
            <select onChange={e => onPageSizeChange(Number(e.target.value))} value={pageSize}>
              {pageSizeOptions.map((option, i) => (
                // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
                <option key={i} value={option}>
                  {`${option} ${this.props.rowsText}`}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </span>
        )}
        <div className="flex-fill text-right">
          Showing {this.getFirstRecord(page, pageSize, totalSize)} thru{' '}
          {this.getLastRecord(page, pageSize, totalSize, currentCount)} of {totalSize}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Last piece of it are some additional pagination props that automatically will propagate to the new component, from my ReactTable setup.

```
<ReactTable
  columns={this.columns}
  data={data}
  pages={pages}
  loading={loading}
  onFetchData={this.handleTableChange}
  defaultPageSize={pageSize}
  defaultSorted={sorted}
  filtered={this.state.filtered}
  filtereable
  getTdProps={this.onRowClick}
  getPaginationProps={() => {
    return {
      totalSize: this.state.totalSize,
      currentCount: this.state.currentCount,
      pageRangeDisplayed: 4,
      marginPagesDisplayed: 1
    }
  }}
  manual
  className={classNames({ '-striped': true, '-highlight': true })}
/>
```

Have some styling somewhere too, but this is the gist of it. This gives me a layout like to picture below.

[image]

Comment: Steve can you share a live link of that demo please

Comment: Sorry, @Amjad, I chucked that at least a year ago. Think I (this is v6) copied the source `src/pagination.js`, made my changes to fit, then did a component override with `PaginationComponent={CustomPaginator}`, but not positive...